# react-rails: Call method of a component like window.Component.method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

is it possible to call a specific method of a component? `window.Component.method` doesn't work...
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
var testClass = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(){
        alert('you clicked me');
    },
    render: function(){
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}></button>
    }
});
```

Dont know if this is a rail-specific thing, but if its just react components you mean, this should do the trick

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. What i actually mean is to call the react method from a javascript file - located lets say in the views...

Comment: Well, why would you wanna do that? That kinda breaks the point of doing react in the first place?

Comment: Right, yes. Just out of curiosity. I always thought that the react methods are part of the window object - seems this is not the case...

Comment: React consists of a virtual dom. Manipulating the dom will get things out of sync.